# How to use zabbix-web-nginx-mysql with existing nginx container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, zabbix

I am trying to use docker on my debian server. There are several sites using Django framework. Every project run in it's own container with gunicorn, single nginx container works as a reverse proxy, data stores in mariadb container. Everything works correctly. It is necessary to add zabbix monitoring system on server. So, I use zabbix-server-mysql image as a zabbix-backend and zabbix-web-nginx-mysql image as a frontend. Backend run successfully, frontend fails with errors such as: "can't binding to 0.0.0.0:80 port is already allocated", nginx refuse connection to domains. As I understand, zabbix-web-nginx-mysql create another nginx container and it causes problems. Is there a right way to use zabbix images with existing nginx container?

Answer (score 0):

I have a nginx reverse proxy installed on the host, which I use for proxy redirect into container. I have a working configuration for docker zabbix with the following configuration (I have omitted the environment variables).

My port 80 for the web application is served through anoter which is same set on nginx proxy_pass. Here the configuration

```
version: '2'
services:
    zabbix-server4:
    container_name: zabbix-server4
    image: zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:alpine-4.0.5
    user: root
    networks:
        zbx_net:
        aliases:
            - zabbix-server4
            - zabbix-server4-mysql
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.5

    zabbix-web4:
    container_name: zabbix-web4
    image: zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql:alpine-4.0.5
    ports: 
        - 127.0.0.1:11011:80
    links:
        - zabbix-server4
    networks:
        zbx_net:
        aliases:
            - zabbix-web4
            - zabbix-web4-nginx-alpine
            - zabbix-web4-nginx-mysql
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10

    zabbix-agent4:
    container_name: zabbix-agent4
    image: zabbix/zabbix-agent:alpine-4.0.5
    links:
        - zabbix-server4
    networks:
        zbx_net:
        aliases:
            - zabbix-agent4
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.15


networks:
zbx_net:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
    com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
    ipam:
    driver: default
    config:
    - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
        gateway: 172.16.238.1
```